# Is it possible to read the content of a SP List from a non sp site?

Tags: javascript

We use SP as our database but our actual website is elsewhere (same network). I need to display the content of a list in a [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) control...it only accepts JSON...I've tried reading the RSS feed and converting it into JSON but its quie a mess.

Any suggestions....?  I cannot use any 3rd party js

Comment: Use the REST API, it will give you JSON results

Answer (score 1):

One very easy option (all client-side or even server-side if you have correct authentication) would be to consume the REST API provided by SharePoint: this API exposes all data in lists with a simple URL, like: `http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items`.
More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx), and in a lot of other articles on the Web.

Comment: Thx, only issue is i'm getting a 404...how do i identify the path to the list and change it for the api..
http://xxx/sites/DGPA/Media%20Monitoring%20and%20Analysis/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: Would be `http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Media Monitoring and Analysis')/items` (if the title of the list is actually "Media Monitoring and Analysis").

Comment: sending it this - http://collaboration/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Media Monitoring and Analysis')/items - but still getting a 404...The path when i browse is http://collaboration/sites/DGPA/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B4853DE23%2D5720%2D48C9%2D9732%2D0C0184BF29A1%7D

do i need to enable anything inside SP?

Comment: Try by steps: 1. `http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web` ; 2. `http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists` ; 3. `http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Media Monitoring and Analysis')` ; 4. `http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Media Monitoring and Analysis')/items` : each one should give you a result. Are you sure about the list title?

Comment: I did have the wrong list name in my first post...but if I go right into SP, to the list Settings I see this under 'Web Address' - http://xxx/sites/DGPA/Lists/MND Quotes/AllItems.aspx

I then attempted the below which all failed (in the browser IE 11)

http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web
http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists
http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MND Quotes')
http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MND Quotes')/items

Comment: 1. The title is not the title you see in the URL: it's the real user-viewable title ('Media Monitoring and Analysis' I guess in your case). 2. Still getting _404_ for all the _api URLs you tried? What about in another browser?

Comment: MND Quotes is the correct list...i had the wrong one earlier.  I cant use any other browser

Comment: **Do they all fail with _404_?** Can you check in the network traces (F12) what's the error?

Comment: YEs, using F12 they all return 404

Comment: What are the user (the one you're running the tests with) permissions on this site?

Comment: Just myself...and I happen to be an admin...

Comment: Sounds like you are doing something basic wrong. Start with just the ``/_api/web/lists`` endpoint and make that work (you have a URI or  authentication problem); after that continue with the desired endpoints

Comment: The uppermost site I have access to is http://xxx/sites/DGPA/SitePages/Home.aspx

I've tried at least 20 variations of 

http://xxx/sites/DGPA/_api/web/lists but they all give me a 404.  I'm simply typing this into the address bar...I really don't know any other way to test this?

Comment: What version of SharePoint?...